# Make SAS report one observation with averages of variables

Tags: sas

I have an SAS program In which I am trying to print only one observation at the end of the file, That observation needs to contain the arithmetic means of 5 variables.  When I run the program I have. I get an error that says

This is my program

```
Filename MyFile '/home/mrohde0/MyFolder/HWData/Funddrive.dat';
libname MyLib '/home/mrohde0/MyFolder/HWData/';
data MyLib.Fund_Avg(drop= Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4 AGEGP Year_Don Ydoncat);
    set MyLib.NewFund end = last;
    retain avgqtr1 0;
    retain avgqtr2 0;
    retain avgqtr3 0;
    retain avgqtr4 0;
    retain avgyear 0;
    retain numObs 0;

    avgqtr1 + qtr1;
    avgqtr2 + qtr2;
    avgqtr3 + qtr3;
    avgqtr4 + qtr4;
    avgyear + Year_don;
    numObs + 1;
    if last then
        DO;
            /* need to divide by number of observations to make these  values the Arithmetic mean */
            avgqtr1 / numObs;
            avgqtr2 / numObs;
            avgqtr3 / numObs;
            avgqtr4 / numObs;
            avgYear / numObs;
            output;
        END;
run;

title1 'Average Funds';
Proc print data=Mylib.fund_avg;
run;
```

When i run the program, this is the error the log reports:

```
 74         if last then  
 75         DO;
 76         avgqtr1 / numObs;
               _______
               180
 77         avgqtr2 / numObs;
               _______
               180
 78         avgqtr3 / numObs;
               _______
               180
 79         avgqtr4 / numObs;
               _______
               180
 80         avgYear / numObs;
               _______
               180
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

I'd like to fix the error above, and make SAS print only the averages that I calculated in a single observation.

Comment: Why not use proc means? This looks painful.

Comment: I agree.  I'm just following instructions.  It's for an assignment.

Comment: Ok... Answer below. I do agree it's good to know how to do this, since extending it does happen on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the calculation to a variable.

```
Avgqtr1 = avgqtr1 / numbObs;
```

Please don't do this though. 
Use proc means or proc SQL.

Proc means will produce a column but proc SQL can produce the row directly.

```
Proc SQL;
 Create table my_lib.fund_avg as
 Select mean(qtr1) as avgqtr1,
        mean(qtr2) as avgqtr2,
        ...
  From my_lib.new_fund:
Quit;
```

Comment: Division doesn't support implicit retain the way the + does. You don't need the retain statement either because + does support implicit retain.

Comment: Edited this comment: I understand now.